# solved | Get text from monaco editor

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

Im trying to get the text from a monaco page but it keeps returning the "full" string:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpJQA.png)

But this is the code in monaco:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0gD6.png)

Here is the code I used:

```
MessageBox.Show(await Monaco.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("editor.getValue()"), "Monaco text:");
```

this is in a async function connected to one of my buttons.

Comment: Don't use external images in your question but post them here. For code use the special syntax for adding code in your question.

Comment: 1. what do you mean by "here"
2. I used special syntax

Comment: ‘Here’ is StackOverflow. Edit your question and add your monaco code.

Comment: But theres nothing that could change the return value. Its editor.getValue (a native function in monaco)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you have Monaco in C#, you can get the text from `webBrowser1` this way:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("GetText");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but all I had to do was `Regex.Unescape` and remove the first and last answer because my issue was that the text was formated in a unusual way, not getting the text